# Cancelling audio clip before starting a new one?

Tags: c#, audio, unity-game-engine, destroy

I almost have a working radio, where the player can walk up to it, press a button and cycle through songs. Everything works except for that with each button press the new song will play but the original will continue to play underneath it. For each new song that is played a new object is created but they are all called 'One Shot Audio,' so I don't know how to destroy them. If I can fix this bug then this should be a useful radio script for anyone who wants to use it.
Update, here is my modified radio code, now working, with the help of the answer below:

```
 void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D target) {
            if (target.gameObject.tag == "radio") {
                radioEnter = true;
            }
    }

    void OnTriggerExit2D(Collider2D target) {
            if (target.gameObject.tag == "radio") {
                radioEnter = false;
            }
    }

   public void radioUse(){
        if ((Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.M)) && song3on == true && radioEnter == true) {
            TurnOn ();
            song1on = true;
            song2on = false;
            song3on = false;
        }
        else if ((Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.M)) && song1on == true && radioEnter == true) {
            TurnOff ();
            song1on = false;
            song2on = true;
            song3on = false;
            TurnOn();
        }
        else if ((Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.M)) && song2on == true && radioEnter == true) {
            TurnOff ();
            song1on = false;
            song2on = false;
            song3on = true;
            TurnOn ();
        }
    }

    public void Update() {
        raidoUse();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Since PlayClipAtPoint does not return an AudioSource to manage you should not use it for these kind of sounds. I recommend setting up your radio with one AudioSource and multiple AudioClips in a array. Just drag the clips you want to the inspector and use the public methods to control the radio. This way you can reuse it with different songs.

The following code is not tested.

```
Public class Radio : MonoBehaviour
{
    AudioSource output;
    public AudioClip[] songs;
    int songIndex = 0;

    void Start(){
        output = gameObject.AddComponent<AudioSource>();
    }

    public void ToggleSong(){
        songIndex++;
        output.clip = songs[songIndex % songs.Length];
        output.Play();
    }

    public void TurnOn(){
        ToggleSong();
    }

    public void TurnOff(){
        output.Stop();
    }
```

Comment: I would love to be able to use these functions- I got as far as the ' output = AddComponent<AudioSource>();' line in the Start function, where 'AddComponent' appears in red. Also, this script is meant to be on the player character correct? Thanks so much again

Comment: The code was intended to use on any radio gameobject in world. But it's just made to show you the functionality. And it's not tested.

Comment: This is because Unity removed the AddComponent from MonoBehaviour and you now need to explicitly use gameObject.AddComponent.

Comment: @fafase Good catch. Changed it. That's what happens when you write the code without testing it. You will probably find more.

Comment: With that update (which I should have known by now, thanks for that) I got your code to work and it runs a radio perfectly!
Thanks!!